# window.open() simply adds the url to my current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use window.open("www.google.com", "_blank");

```
window.open("www.google.com", "_blank");
```

A new tab is opened, but the url isn't "www.google.com", it's "=url-i-was-at=/www.google.com".

This is a snippet of the code (and the only relevant code).
http://jsfiddle.net/FUYTY/

In jsfiddle it behaves a bit differently, but still doesn't work as it should.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `www.google.com` would be a local path, referring to for example a directory of the same name on your server. What you you need to link to an external domain instead is an absolute URL, so something like `http://www.google.com/`.

Comment: Not sure why this is being so heavily downvoted. It's a valid question  with a clear solution.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You wanted to access the root document of server `www.google.com`, which is done using the url `https://www.google.com/`. You provided a relative url for document `www.google.com` instead.

Keep in mind that `window.open` accepts both relative and absolute urls, so it can't assume you left out `https://` as it does when you use `www.google.com` in the address bar.

---

Maybe an example will help. Say the current page is `http://www.example.com/dir/foo.html`.

- `window.open("popup.html", "_blank")` opens
  `http://www.example.com/dir/popup.html`.
- `window.open("www.google.com", "_blank")` therefore opens
  `http://www.example.com/dir/www.google.com`.

The browser has no way of knowing you actually wanted `https://www.google.com/` when you said you wanted `http://www.example.com/dir/www.google.com` since the latter could be valid.

Comment: Great, thanks! Why does including http:// fix it though? HTML/JS or whatever controls it looks for the http and if it doesn't find it it interprets it as a relative url?

Comment: Maybe an example will help. `window.open` accepts relative and absolute urls. If you call `window.open("popup.html", "_blank")` from `http://www.example.com/dir/foo.html`, it will open `http://www.example.com/dir/popup.html`. If you call `window.open("www.google.com", "_blank")` from the same page, it will open `http://www.example.com/dir/www.google.com`. The browser has no way of knowing you actually wanted `http://www.google.com/` when you said you wanted `http://www.example.com/dir/www.google.com`.

Comment: save my time just struggle last 30 mints

Answer (score 15):

You have to prepend `http://` in your url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mybtn').on('click', function () {
        window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
    });
});
```

Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/FUYTY/4/

Answer (score 5):

Try adding http:// beforehand (see Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/FUYTY/3/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#mybtn').on('click', function() {
      window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');   
  });
});
```

Some more information:
If you include a '/' beforehand, it appends your string to the root URL.  If you just list the string, it appends it to the current full URL.  If you include either http:// or https:// it knows to use only what you put in your string (i.e. http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 4):

Preface your urls with `http://`