# Why href of <a> tag get appended to my current address?

Tags: html, struts2, action

I have a simple  tag which has a url as its href, when I click on it, it appends the URL to the current address.

The address is www.example.com/event/

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com" taget="_blank">Here</a>
```

When I click on it, it will change to following

```
 www.example.com/event/www.yahoo.com
```

Comment: are you using a framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.open() simply adds the url to my current url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373990/window-open-simply-adds-the-url-to-my-current-url)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a relative URI. Add `http://` to make it an absolute URI:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Here</a>
```

Comment: (Also note that the attribute is `target`, not `taget` as in the post..)

Comment: You should always use `https://`. You also could link to just `//www.yahoo.com` than the same protocol as the current page is used.